# All jobs on one core fail with R multicore

Tags: r, multicore, mclapply

I'm using R multicore on a long list. I invoke `mclapply` on the list, which makes use of 12 cores on my machine.

When my list has about 1000 elements long it runs fine.
When my list is longer than ~2000 elements (I'm not sure at what length this behaviour kicks in) then all jobs submitted to core 5 fail.

(I found this out by submitting the list element ids to [this website](http://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C17%2C29%2C41%2C53%2C65%2C77%2C89%2C101%2C113%2C125&language=english&go=Search).)

I have tried this on several nodes but I always get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In mclapply(h.list, train_and_predict, learn.bias = F, ntree = ntree,  :
  scheduled core 5 encountered error in user code, all values of the job will be affected
```

**Q: Why would only one core fail?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PK

Comment: I've had this happen too.  Interested in any ideas!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example which reproduces this issue.

Comment: When this happened to me it was always because some element of the full list was breaking my code -- while none on the shorter list did.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra: The data I used is quite big (~100MiB). Would you be able to grab that?

Comment: You can provide us with a link to the file, without such an example it is hard to go beyond speculation as to why this happens, and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens when at least one datum activates a bug in your code. `multicore` cannot recover and all the data on that core is corrupted. `mclapply` partitions the data evenly across all nodes and if it fails for even one datum on one node.

I would suggest the following solution: start with `M` of `N` data items; if it fails then gradually decrease `M` until it works; then the `M+1` datum is faulty. Run your code serially (that is, without using `mclapply`) with the `M+1`-th datum only and see where it fails. Then that is the bug.